# how to get different position content under same element?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am new to xml and xsl, if this is a easy question, and if my term is not correct, I am sorry for that.

My question is that, the "ab" and "cd" belong to  element, however in xsl, the xpath expression "../text()", always point to "ab", but not "cd".
Is there any way I can get "cd"? Thanks a lot!

xml:

```
<root>
ab
<CH>xxxx</CH>
cd
<CH>xxxx</CH>
</root>
```

xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
          xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
      <xsl:template match="root" >
          <xsl:apply-templates select="CH"/>

    </xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="CH" >
    <c> 
        <xsl:value-of select="../text()"/>
    </c>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

current result:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<c>
ab
</c><c>
ab
</c>
```

desire result:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<c>
ab
</c><c>
cd
</c>
```

---

sorry, missing the sample code

`<root>
    ab
    <CH>xxxx</CH>
    cd
    <CH>xxxx</CH>
    </root>`

```
current result: <c>ab</c><c>ab</c> 
desire result: <c>ab</c><c>cd</c>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
../text()
```

returns the two text nodes which are children of your parent.

1. ab
2. cd

```
<xsl:value-of select="../text()" />
```

implicitly added a `[1]` to filter the select statement to the first item in the select statement. There are a number of ways to select the appropriate text node, using `preceding-sibling::` as suggested by Alejandro is probably the best for your problem, but another solution which makes it clearer what is happening with your current `../text()` expression would be to change the template to:

```
<xsl:template match="CH" >
    <xsl:variable name="position" select="position()"/>
    <c> 
        <xsl:value-of select="../text()[$position]"/>
    </c>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are looking for the `preceding-sibling` axis.

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="root" >
        <xsl:apply-templates select="CH"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="CH" >
        <c>
            <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::text()[1]"/>
        </c>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<c> ab
</c><c> cd 
</c>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
      xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="root">
      <xsl:apply-templates select ="CH"/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="CH" >
      <c><xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::text()[1]"/>
      </c>
</xsl:template>
```

Mention by Nick Jones, we can use "preceding-sibling" as well to resolve the problem, I just post here in case anyone interests.